# how to display the number of seconds with two digits after the decimal point

Tags: javascript, node.js

using the code posted below, i am trying to create a date-time in the following formate:

```
YYY-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ
```

despite i set `new Date().getSeconds().toFixed(2)`, i get the output posted below, in which the `seconds` part is composed of three zeros after the decimal point.
what i want to do is, to display the `seconds` part with two digits after the decimal point.

i want the range to look like the following:

```
2012-06-01T09:54:18.00Z
```

how can i achieve that please

**code**:

```
static getTimeRangeFor(day, month, year) {
    let msg = undefined;
    const nowHours = new Date().getHours();
    const nowMinutes = new Date().getMinutes();
    const nowSeconds = new Date().getSeconds().toFixed(0);
    const asDate = new Date(year + '-' + month + '-' + day + ' ' + nowHours + ':' + nowMinutes + ':' + nowSeconds);
    const asTimeRange = new Date(year + '-' + month + '-' + day + ' ' + nowHours + ':' + nowMinutes + ':' + nowSeconds).getTime();

    msg = JSON.stringify({ msg: infoTag + 'getTimeRangeFor():',asDate:asDate});
    console.info(msg);
    msg = JSON.stringify({ msg: infoTag + 'getTimeRangeFor():',asTimeRange:asTimeRange});
    console.info(msg);

    const obj = {
        asTimeRange,
        asDate,
        nowHours,
        nowMinutes,
        nowSeconds,
    };
    return obj;
}
```

**output**

```
2012-06-01T09:54:18.000Z
```

Comment: What you are logging to the console there, are `Date` objects. And those come with their own `toString` implementation, that dictates _how_ they are transformed into a string value. _"despite i set `new Date().getSeconds().toFixed(2)`"_ - that is only your _input_ value, that you are then using as a parameter in your `new Date(...)` call. It has no influence on what happens after you created the Date instance.

Comment: @CBroe but the backend expect the date-time in the following format YYYY-MM-ddddThh:mm:ssZ ? isnt there any solution please

Comment: You have currently only shown us how you fill a JS object, what happens with that afterwards, how it gets send to the backend, is unclear. And your JS object is filled with a Date instance, not with a formatted value in string form - so that conversion must happens somewhere later on.

Answer (score 0):

The "ISO date" in javascript always has 3 digits for the second-fractions part.
See: [21.4.1.32 Date Time String Format](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-date-time-string-format).

So you need to modify the ISO time string, or build a custom "to ISO string" function.

You can explicitly get an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) time-string with:

```
const myIsoDateString = asDate.toISOString(); // --> e.g. "2012-06-01T09:54:18.000Z"
```

You could manipulate this string in different ways. I'd suggest:

```
const [ fromYearsToSeconds, fractions ] = myIsoDateString.split('.');
const withTwoDigits = fromYearsToSeconds + '.' + fractions.substring(0,2) + 'Z' //
```